# R's ggplot2: How to custom-make or force a legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm attempting to add a legend to my ggplot graph even though I wasn't effectively using that variable for color. I'd like it to look like a gradient of color with a label that shows it's the distance variable. The trouble is that by adding custom color, shape, and size, it seems I can't have a legend, even when I put all the colors in aes and specify scale_color_manual.

I've separated geom_points by their index of "outlier-ness" and binned them in order to have fine-tuned control over size, color, alpha, and shape of these points. I know I can probably get a legend by deleting all the manual control, but I would much prefer if I could keep manual control for these values and still have a legend. It's fine if I have to custom build a legend through grobs, I'm just not quite sure how to do that.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(stats)
library(dplyr)
library(OutliersO3)
library(FastPCS)
library(cowplot)

outlierplottest <-
  function(x,
           y,
           labels = NULL,
           alpha = NULL,
           withcolor = TRUE) {
    #........................Alpha Adjustment........................
    
    if (is.null(alpha)) {
      if (length(x) > 2000) {
        alpha <- .1
      } else if (length(x) > 1000) {
        alpha <- .3
      } else if (length(x) > 500) {
        alpha <- .5
      } else if (length(x) > 300) {
        alpha <- .7
      } else if (length(x) > 100) {
        alpha <- .8
      } else if (length(x) > 20) {
        alpha <- .9
      } else{
        alpha <- 1
      }
      
    }
    
    if (withcolor == FALSE & length(x) > 50) {
      alpha <- (alpha + .1) / 2
    }
    if (withcolor == FALSE & length(x) > 200) {
      alpha <- (alpha + .02) / 2
    }
    
    #...................Initial Dataframe Creation...................
    
    if (!is.null(labels)) {
      df <- data.frame("x" = x,
                       "y" = y,
                       "labels" = labels)
      
    } else {
      df <- data.frame("x" = x ,
                       "y" = y)
      
    }
    
    #..........2D Outlier Detection And Statistical Distance.........
    
    df.twocols <- df[, c("x", "y")]
    
    pcs.results <- FastPCS(df.twocols)
    
    df$distance <- pcs.results$distance
    
    a0 <-
      O3prep(
        df.twocols,
        method = "PCS",
        tols = 0.05,
        boxplotLimits = 3
      )
    
    outlier.indexes <- a0$outList$outM[[3]]$outlierIndices
    
    df.outliers <- df[outlier.indexes, ]
    
    df.regulars <- df[-(outlier.indexes), ]
    
    #................Creating & Dividing Up Dataframes...............
    
    if (length(x) > 1000) {
      labelpercent <- .005
    } else if (length(x) > 100) {
      labelpercent <- 1
    } else if (length(x) > 50) {
      labelpercent <- 2
    } else {
      labelpercent <- 3
    }
    
    to.label <-
      df.outliers[df.outliers$distance > quantile(df.outliers$distance, prob =
                                                    1 - labelpercent / 100),]
    
    outside.top5 <-
      df.outliers[df.outliers$distance > quantile(df.outliers$distance, prob =
                                                    1 - 5 / 100),]
    outside.5.thru.20 <-
      df.outliers[df.outliers$distance > quantile(df.outliers$distance, prob =
                                                    1 - 20 / 100) &
                    df.outliers$distance < quantile(df.outliers$distance, prob = 1 -
                                                      5 / 100),]
    outside.20.thru.40 <-
      df.outliers[df.outliers$distance > quantile(df.outliers$distance, prob =
                                                    1 - 40 / 100) &
                    df.outliers$distance < quantile(df.outliers$distance, prob = 1 -
                                                      20 / 100),]
    outside.40.thru.60 <-
      df.outliers[df.outliers$distance > quantile(df.outliers$distance, prob =
                                                    1 - 60 / 100) &
                    df.outliers$distance < quantile(df.outliers$distance, prob = 1 -
                                                      40 / 100),]
    outside.60.thru.80 <-
      df.outliers[df.outliers$distance > quantile(df.outliers$distance, prob =
                                                    1 - 80 / 100) &
                    df.outliers$distance < quantile(df.outliers$distance, prob = 1 -
                                                      60 / 100),]
    outside.80.thru.100 <-
      df.outliers[df.outliers$distance < quantile(df.outliers$distance, prob =
                                                    1 - 80 / 100),]
    
    inside.top20 <-
      df.regulars[df.regulars$distance > quantile(df.regulars$distance, prob =
                                                    1 - 20 / 100),]
    inside.20.thru.40 <-
      df.regulars[df.regulars$distance > quantile(df.regulars$distance, prob =
                                                    1 - 40 / 100) &
                    df.regulars$distance < quantile(df.regulars$distance, prob = 1 -
                                                      20 / 100),]
    inside.40.thru.60 <-
      df.regulars[df.regulars$distance > quantile(df.regulars$distance, prob =
                                                    1 - 60 / 100) &
                    df.regulars$distance < quantile(df.regulars$distance, prob = 1 -
                                                      40 / 100),]
    inside.60.thru.80 <-
      df.regulars[df.regulars$distance > quantile(df.regulars$distance, prob =
                                                    1 - 80 / 100) &
                    df.regulars$distance < quantile(df.regulars$distance, prob = 1 -
                                                      60 / 100),]
    inside.80.thru.100 <-
      df.regulars[df.regulars$distance < quantile(df.regulars$distance, prob =
                                                    1 - 80 / 100),]
    
    #..........................Creating Plot.........................
    
    if (withcolor == TRUE) {
      #......................Creating Plot: Color......................
      
      # Version 1:
      # p <- ggplot() +
      # Version 2:
      # p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=x, y=y, color = distance)) +
      # Version 3:
      p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
        
        geom_point(
          data = outside.top5,
          aes(
            x = x,
            y = y,
            color = "outside.top5",
            size = 3.5 * 1.05
          ),
          shape = 1,
          alpha = 1
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.top5,
          aes(
            x = x,
            y = y,
            color = "outside.top5",
            size = 1.5 * 1.05
          ),
          shape = 16,
          alpha = 1
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.5.thru.20,
          aes(
            x = x,
            y = y,
            color = "outside.5.thru.20",
            size = 3.5
          ),
          shape = 1,
          alpha = (alpha + .9) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.5.thru.20,
          aes(
            x = x,
            y = y,
            color = "outside.5.thru.20",
            size = 1.5
          ),
          shape = 16,
          alpha = (alpha + .9) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.20.thru.40,
          aes(
            x = x,
            y = y,
            color = "outside.20.thru.40",
            size = 3.5
          ),
          shape = 1,
          alpha = (alpha + .8) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.20.thru.40,
          aes(
            x = x,
            y = y,
            color = "outside.20.thru.40",
            size = 1.5
          ),
          shape = 16,
          alpha = (alpha + .8) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.40.thru.60,
          aes(
            x = x,
            y = y,
            color = "outside.40.thru.60",
            size = 3.5
          ),
          shape = 1,
          alpha = (alpha + .7) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.40.thru.60,
          aes(
            x = x,
            y = y,
            color = "outside.40.thru.60",
            size = 1.5
          ),
          shape = 16,
          alpha = (alpha + .7) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.60.thru.80,
          aes(
            x = x,
            y = y,
            color = "outside.60.thru.80",
            size = 3.5
          ),
          shape = 1,
          alpha = (alpha + .6) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.60.thru.80,
          aes(
            x = x,
            y = y,
            color = "outside.60.thru.80",
            size = 1.5
          ),
          shape = 16,
          alpha = (alpha + .6) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.80.thru.100,
          aes(
            x = x,
            y = y,
            color = "outside.80.thru.100",
            size = 3.5
          ),
          shape = 1,
          alpha = (alpha + .4) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.80.thru.100,
          aes(
            x = x,
            y = y,
            color = "outside.80.thru.100",
            size = 1.5
          ),
          shape = 16,
          alpha = (alpha + .4) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = inside.top20,
          aes(
            x = x,
            y = y,
            color = "inside.top20",
            size = 1.3
          ),
          alpha = (alpha + .3) / 2,
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = inside.20.thru.40,
          aes(
            x = x,
            y = y,
            color = "inside.20.thru.40",
            size = 1.1
          ),
          alpha = (alpha + .3) / 2,
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = inside.40.thru.60,
          aes(
            x = x,
            y = y,
            color = "inside.40.thru.60",
            size = .9
          ),
          alpha = (alpha + .3) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = inside.60.thru.80,
          aes(
            x = x,
            y = y,
            color = "inside.60.thru.80",
            size = .8
          ),
          alpha = (alpha + .3) / 2,
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = inside.80.thru.100,
          aes(
            x = x,
            y = y,
            color = "inside.80.thru.100",
            size = .7
          ),
          alpha = (alpha + .3) / 2,
        ) +
        scale_color_manual(
          guide = guide_legend(),
          values = c(
            inside.80.thru.100 = "#2e60d1",
            inside.60.thru.80 = "#0079db",
            inside.40.thru.60 = "#008fdc",
            inside.20.thru.40 = "#00a1d7",
            inside.top20 = "#2eb2d1",
            outside.80.thru.100 = "#2eb2d1",
            outside.60.thru.80 = "#589de6",
            outside.40.thru.60 = "#ac79cf",
            outside.20.thru.40 = "#dc5089",
            outside.5.thru.20 = "#d14d2e",
            outside.top5 = "#D12E60"
          )
        )
      
    } else {
      #..................Creating Plot: Black & White..................
      p <- ggplot() +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.top5,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          shape = 1,
          size = 3.5 * 1.05,
          alpha = 1
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.top5,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          shape = 16,
          size = 1.5 * 1.05,
          alpha = 1
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.5.thru.20,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          shape = 1,
          size = 3.5,
          alpha = (alpha + .9) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.5.thru.20,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          shape = 16,
          size = 1.5,
          alpha = (alpha + .9) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.20.thru.40,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          shape = 1,
          size = 3.5,
          alpha = (alpha + .8) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.20.thru.40,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          shape = 16,
          size = 1.5,
          alpha = (alpha + .8) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.40.thru.60,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          shape = 1,
          size = 3.5,
          alpha = (alpha + .7) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.40.thru.60,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          shape = 16,
          size = 1.5,
          alpha = (alpha + .7) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.60.thru.80,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          shape = 1,
          size = 3.5,
          alpha = (alpha + .6) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.60.thru.80,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          shape = 16,
          size = 1.5,
          alpha = (alpha + .6) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.80.thru.100,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          shape = 1,
          size = 3.5,
          alpha = (alpha + .4) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.80.thru.100,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          shape = 16,
          size = 1.5,
          alpha = (alpha + .4) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = inside.top20,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          alpha = (alpha + .3) / 2,
          size = 1.3
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = inside.20.thru.40,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          alpha = (alpha + .3) / 2,
          size = 1.1
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = inside.40.thru.60,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          alpha = (alpha + .3) / 2,
          size = .9
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = inside.60.thru.80,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          alpha = (alpha + .3) / 2,
          size = .8
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = inside.80.thru.100,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          alpha = (alpha + .3) / 2,
          size = .7
        )
      
    }
    
    if (!is.null(labels)) {
      p <- p + geom_text(
        data = to.label,
        vjust = 0,
        nudge_y = 1,
        check_overlap = TRUE,
        aes(x = x, y = y, label = labels)
        
      )
      
    }
    
    #.........................Returning Plot.........................
    
    return(p)
    
  }


diamonds <- ggplot2::diamonds
p <- outlierplot(x = diamonds$carat, y = diamonds$depth)
p
```

Here is another version of the code that also didn't work:

```
outlierplot <-
  function(x,
           y,
           labels = NULL,
           alpha = NULL,
           withcolor = TRUE) {

    #........................Alpha Adjustment........................

    if (is.null(alpha)) {
      if (length(x) > 2000) {
        alpha <- .1
      } else if (length(x) > 1000) {
        alpha <- .3
      } else if (length(x) > 500) {
        alpha <- .5
      } else if (length(x) > 300) {
        alpha <- .7
      } else if (length(x) > 100) {
        alpha <- .8
      } else if (length(x) > 20) {
        alpha <- .9
      } else{
        alpha <- 1
      }

    }

    if (withcolor == FALSE & length(x) > 50) {
      alpha <- (alpha + .1) / 2
    }
    if (withcolor == FALSE & length(x) > 200) {
      alpha <- (alpha + .02) / 2
    }

    #...................Initial Dataframe Creation...................

    if (!is.null(labels)) {
      df <- data.frame("x" = x,
                       "y" = y,
                       "labels" = labels)

    } else {
      df <- data.frame("x" = x ,
                       "y" = y)

    }

    #..........2D Outlier Detection And Statistical Distance.........

    df.twocols <- df[,c("x","y")]

    pcs.results <- FastPCS(df.twocols)

    df$distance <- pcs.results$distance

    a0 <- O3prep(df.twocols, method="PCS", tols=0.05, boxplotLimits=3)

    outlier.indexes <- a0$outList$outM[[3]]$outlierIndices

    df.outliers <- df[outlier.indexes,]

    df.regulars <- df[-(outlier.indexes),]

    #................Creating & Dividing Up Dataframes...............

    if(length(x) > 1000){
      labelpercent <- .005
    } else if(length(x) > 100){
      labelpercent <- 1
    } else if(length(x) > 50){
      labelpercent <- 2
    } else {
      labelpercent <- 3
    }

    to.label <-
      df.outliers[df.outliers$distance > quantile(df.outliers$distance, prob =
                                                           1 - labelpercent / 100), ]

    outside.top5 <-
      df.outliers[df.outliers$distance > quantile(df.outliers$distance, prob =
                                                           1 - 5 / 100), ]
    outside.5.thru.20 <-
      df.outliers[df.outliers$distance > quantile(df.outliers$distance, prob =
                                                           1 - 20 / 100) &
                    df.outliers$distance < quantile(df.outliers$distance, prob = 1 -
                                                             5 / 100), ]
    outside.20.thru.40 <-
      df.outliers[df.outliers$distance > quantile(df.outliers$distance, prob =
                                                           1 - 40 / 100) &
                    df.outliers$distance < quantile(df.outliers$distance, prob = 1 -
                                                             20 / 100), ]
    outside.40.thru.60 <-
      df.outliers[df.outliers$distance > quantile(df.outliers$distance, prob =
                                                           1 - 60 / 100) &
                    df.outliers$distance < quantile(df.outliers$distance, prob = 1 -
                                                             40 / 100), ]
    outside.60.thru.80 <-
      df.outliers[df.outliers$distance > quantile(df.outliers$distance, prob =
                                                           1 - 80 / 100) &
                    df.outliers$distance < quantile(df.outliers$distance, prob = 1 -
                                                             60 / 100), ]
    outside.80.thru.100 <-
      df.outliers[df.outliers$distance < quantile(df.outliers$distance, prob =
                                                           1 - 80 / 100), ]

    inside.top20 <-
      df.regulars[df.regulars$distance > quantile(df.regulars$distance, prob =
                                                         1 - 20 / 100), ]
    inside.20.thru.40 <-
      df.regulars[df.regulars$distance > quantile(df.regulars$distance, prob =
                                                         1 - 40 / 100) &
                    df.regulars$distance < quantile(df.regulars$distance, prob = 1 -
                                                           20 / 100), ]
    inside.40.thru.60 <-
      df.regulars[df.regulars$distance > quantile(df.regulars$distance, prob =
                                                         1 - 60 / 100) &
                    df.regulars$distance < quantile(df.regulars$distance, prob = 1 -
                                                           40 / 100), ]
    inside.60.thru.80 <-
      df.regulars[df.regulars$distance > quantile(df.regulars$distance, prob =
                                                         1 - 80 / 100) &
                    df.regulars$distance < quantile(df.regulars$distance, prob = 1 -
                                                           60 / 100), ]
    inside.80.thru.100 <-
      df.regulars[df.regulars$distance < quantile(df.regulars$distance, prob =
                                                         1 - 80 / 100), ]

    #..........................Creating Plot.........................

    if (withcolor == TRUE) {

      #......................Creating Plot: Color......................

      p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(color = distance)) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.top5,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          shape = 1,
          color = "#D12E60",
          size = 3.5 * 1.05,
          alpha = 1
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.top5,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          shape = 16,
          color = "#D12E60",
          size = 1.5 * 1.05,
          alpha = 1
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.5.thru.20,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          shape = 1,
          color = "#d14d2e",
          size = 3.5,
          alpha = (alpha + .9) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.5.thru.20,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          shape = 16,
          color = "#d14d2e",
          size = 1.5,
          alpha = (alpha + .9) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.20.thru.40,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          shape = 1,
          color = "#dc5089",
          size = 3.5,
          alpha = (alpha + .8) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.20.thru.40,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          shape = 16,
          color = "#dc5089",
          size = 1.5,
          alpha = (alpha + .8) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.40.thru.60,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          shape = 1,
          color = "#ac79cf",
          size = 3.5,
          alpha = (alpha + .7) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.40.thru.60,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          shape = 16,
          color = "#ac79cf",
          size = 1.5,
          alpha = (alpha + .7) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.60.thru.80,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          shape = 1,

          color = "#589de6",
          size = 3.5,
          alpha = (alpha + .6) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.60.thru.80,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          shape = 16,
          color = "#589de6",
          size = 1.5,
          alpha = (alpha + .6) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.80.thru.100,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          shape = 1,

          color = "#2eb2d1",
          size = 3.5,
          alpha = (alpha + .4) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = outside.80.thru.100,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          shape = 16,
          color = "#2eb2d1",
          size = 1.5,
          alpha = (alpha + .4) / 2
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = inside.top20,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          alpha = (alpha + .3) / 2,
          color = "#2eb2d1",
          size = 1.3
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = inside.20.thru.40,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          alpha = (alpha + .3) / 2,
          color = "#00a1d7",
          size = 1.1
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = inside.40.thru.60,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          alpha = (alpha + .3) / 2,
          color = "#008fdc",
          size = .9
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = inside.60.thru.80,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          alpha = (alpha + .3) / 2,
          color = "#0079db",
          size = .8
        ) +
        geom_point(
          data = inside.80.thru.100,
          aes(x = x, y = y),
          alpha = (alpha + .3) / 2,
          color = "#2e60d1",
          size = .7
        )

    } else {

      #..................Creating Plot: Black & White..................

      ...
```

Comment: I think you'll be more likely to get more useful suggestions if you can make this (much) more minimal. You have 140 lines of code before you get to the ggplot code, and then you have  17 layers: 6 of shape 1, 6 of shape 16, and 5 of the default 19 shape. I presume it would get the point across to include a small sample of "already prepared" data (e.g. `dput(MY_DATA[1:20,])` to make a recipe for the first 20 lines), and then enough geom_point layers to create the general issue you're trying to address (maybe 3-5?).

Comment: BTW, you can specify alpha as part of a custom hex color, if you want to simplify the color/alpha combinations of the layers. For instance, "#dc508980" is "#dc5089" with 50% alpha.

Comment: In addition to what @JonSpring said, I find that if your plotting function is more that ~15-20 lines of code, you are probably over complicating things. I feel like this code could be condensed by at least 80% by using factors, mapping variables to dataframes, and/or passing `...` to the `geom_point` calls.